# AJAX call throws 500 error on server, but works at local

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application, and I use AJAX call somewhere in it. It works everything fine locally, but when I deploy it on server, it throws error 500 on ajax call without any additional information. I cannot check server logs, Kibana also empty. Notes: CORS enabled in app, server: JBoss Web/3.0.0-CR2

Part of JavaScript with AJAX call

```
    $('#myTable3').DataTable({
        lengthMenu: [ [ 3, 5, 10, 25, 50, -1 ], [ 3, 5, 10, 25, 50, "All" ] ],
        ajax: {
            type: "GET",
            url: "/*******/comparision-result/search-edm" + "?" + params,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 600000,
            dataSrc: '',
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                console.log(error);
                console.log(err.Message);
            }
        }
    });
```

Part of java controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/comparision-result/search-edm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @CrossOrigin
    public @ResponseBody
    Object[] getSearchResultForComparisionEdm(@RequestParam("hours") String hours, @RequestParam("pattern") String pattern, HttpSession session) {
```

Please figure out what is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, issue appeared in code, but that Ajax request is too heavy, so, it makes big load to server. Solution is increase server capacity or optimize request